# Draw a pencil stripe in OSx using swift

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to draw a pencil stripe in a NSImageView using this code:

```
class DrawView: NSImageView
{
  var point = NSPoint()
  override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect)
  {
    let myContext = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.CGContext
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor (myContext, 1, 0, 0, 1)
    CGContextAddArc(myContext, point.x, point.y,1,0.1,0,0)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(myContext, 1)
    CGContextStrokePath(myContext)
  }

  func MousePan(mouseLocation: NSPoint)
  {
    point = mouseLocation
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
  }
}
```

So far nearly everything works fine, I get a red point on my mousepointer as soon as I click on my view an move the mouse.
My problem is that I don't get a stripe on my view, just this little red point. 
What do I have to do, to get this thing working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should be using a subclass of `NSView`, not `NSImageView`.

And the methods are little bit off.

It goes more like:

- `CGContextMoveToPoint`
- Then `CGContextLineToPoint` or `CGContextCurvedLineToPoint`
- Then *if necessary*, `CGContextClosePath`
- Then `CGContextStrokePath`